# How can I change laravel Hashing to be using Hash_hmac(Sha3-512,'mykey') instead of Bcrypt?

Tags: laravel, hash, hmac, laravel-6

I have a client whose existing database implements sha3-512 using the hmac, and I am building a laravel app that will make use of their existing user data which is on sha3-512 hash. They have existing app already using same service. It means i have to make laravel to use sha3-512 instead of Bcrypt.
Anyone knows how I can achieve this feat?
I have looked and tried suggestion here
[Changing Laravel 5.4 password encryption and table column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704782/changing-laravel-5-4-password-encryption-and-table-column-names)
But it did not work.

Thank you guys.

Comment: I need to add that I am using laravel 6

Comment: So edit your question and add the `laravel-6` tag :)